# Time-delay file editing

Tags: files, permissions, encryption

In pharmacies, certain drugs are put in a time-delay safe, which means there is a fixed lag between the retrieval request and the time the safe is able to open (say maybe 15 minutes). I'm wondering if it's possible to do this with the editing permissions of a file, where the delay is enforced even if you're root.

And, if this is not possible, is it possible to encrypt a file in a time-delayed manner? Something more elegant and precise than "it would take about n years to brute force it".

Comment: Exclude root and this issue could be achievable. Root is the administrative account, though, so if you give someone access to this account you have given them the system.

Comment: this sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) about to happen, or maybe just some weird what-if hypothetical. What problem are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: @cas I'm interested in getting an answer to exactly what's described, in full generality. Basically there's a user who needs occasional root access and I don't want them to be able to modify a specific file on the machine until they've had at least n minutes to potentially think about it.

Comment: @roaima how would this be possible if we exclude root? That could possibly work

Comment: @bxw if you don't trust them, then don't give them root.   Or if you only want them to edit one file as root, then write a wrapper script that has a sleep or other delay in it before running `$EDITOR /path/to/file` and then give them `sudo` access to only that script and not to all commands (or any other command that could edit the file).   `sudo` **doesn't** have to allow **everything** to be run as root (in fact, that was very unusual until a decade or two ago when unix became common/cheap enough for users to own their own unix workstations and had to administer them for themselves).

Comment: Giving sudo access to a wrapper script is the right way to allow partially-privileged users to do some tasks as root, but not others.   BTW, you'd probably be better off putting the file into revision control with `git` or similar, (if it's in /etc, just install [etckeeper](https://etckeeper.branchable.com/)) and making regular backups - if they break it, you can easily revert.    You can also use `chattr` to make a file immutable until chattr is run on it again to remove immutability.  This will, at least, cause a short delay to allow a chance for second thoughts before editing the file.

Comment: that second part about encryption is definitely off-topic, it should be on security.SE or crypto.SE. But then I think it might already have been discussed there. (The answer is "no".)

Comment: @cas Thanks for the suggestions. I trust them to do everything except edit this single file. The file is a set of configurations for a series of running processes, spawned many times per minute. Any bad edit to the file will cause problems immediately. Version control doesn't quite work in this case.

Comment: You can assume for the purposes of this discussion that the obvious solution (bake the delay into the way the process functions) is not viable.

Comment: Then take a tip from `visudo` - don't let them edit the file directly, let them edit a copy of it and check that there are no syntax errors.  e.g. make the file immutable, write a "edit_my_special_file" script that copies it, runs $EDITOR on the copy, checks that the result of the edit has no errors and if it does, remove the immutable attribute on the original, replace it with the new version, and make it immutable again.   Note that like `visudo`, this can only verify that the syntax is valid, it can not check that what the new config file does is actually sane or does anything useful.

Comment: and you should still use version control. Reverting to the last known-good, working version of a file from the history is a **lot** quicker and easier than trying to figure out what your co-worker did and undo-ing it.   The commits can be automated in the scripts too - commit the current version before editing if `git status` says that it has been modified but not yet commited (message could be something like "autocommit before edit").  A successful edit would trigger a commit with a message like "Edited by $SUDO_USER".

Comment: The diffs from these commits can be used to see what was done in each edit, and is especially useful for teaching (not berating!) your co-worker what they did wrong and how to do it correctly.   BTW, even just knowing that every edit is tracked can be enough to encourage caution when editing the file.

Answer (score 3):

You clarified in a [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/663930/time-delay-file-editing?noredirect=1#comment1249017_663930) that

> there's a user who needs occasional root access and I don't want them to be able to modify a specific file on the machine until they've had at least *n* minutes to potentially think about it.

I might approach this in one of a number of ways. I assume it's a single file that should be considered for editing.

Consider a script `/usr/local/bin/myedit`. Add the user into the group `myeditors`, or if it really will ever only be a single user, change the `%myeditors` value to the username. Using `visudo` add this line to the `sudoers` file

```
%myeditors ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/myedit
```

Now create the script `/usr/local/bin/myedit`, remembering to make it executable (`chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/myedit`).

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# THIS SCRIPT RUNS AS ROOT
#
# %myeditors ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/myedit
########################################################################

# User configurable values
target='/usr/local/etc/specialfile'    # The file to be edited
delay=600                              # Delay in seconds

########################################################################
# Here we go
#
progName="${0##*/}"

# Reset PATH to known quantity
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin

# Force the script to run with sudo
[[ $(id -u) != 0 ]] && exec sudo "$0" "$@"

printf 'Waiting %d seconds...' $delay
sleep $delay && echo

read -t 60 -p "Are you sure you still want to edit $target (y/N)? " YN
[[ "${YN,,}" =~ ^(y|yes)$ ]] || exit 1

umask 0022
tmpf=$(mktemp -d "/tmp/${progName}_XXXXXXXXXX")
cp -f "$target" "$tmpf"

# Revert to the original user account to edit the temporary file
chown "$SUDO_USER" "$tmpf"
sudo -u "$SUDO_USER" "${EDITOR:-vi}" "$tmpf"

# Apply changes
if [[ -f "$tmpf" ]] && ! cmp -s "$target" "$tmpf"
then
    echo 'Applying changes'
    cp -pf "$target" "$target.old"
    cp -f "$tmpf" "$target"
fi

# All done
rm -f "$tmpf"
exit 0
```

Invoke the command *without* `sudo` (although it doesn't matter if you use it):

```
myedit
```

Comment: or let them edit first, then force them to stare at the edited file for those 600 seconds before putting it in place...